# Select code block between two tags VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way or an extension in VSCode to select a code block between 2 tags,

i have a large file about **90000** lines of code, lets say i will put two tags in two different lines, at line **331** and **2210** for example

```
331   #MY_TAG
332   .......
333   .......
334   .......
2210  #MY_TAG
```

is there a way to select the lines between **#MY_TAG** with a keyboard shortcut or an extension which allow that.